# how to navigate to homescreen onPress of login button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, forms-authentication, stack-navigator

**onPress** of login button, I want to navigate to some other screen basically a home screen with authentication taking username and password. I am using a  `stack navigator` but when I click on login button it just hits the API and nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import {
     StyleSheet,
     Platform,
     Text,
     Image,
     View,TouchableOpacity,ImageBackground,ScrollView,AsyncStorage
   } from 'react-native';

   const instructions = Platform.select({
     ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
       'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
     android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
       'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
   });

   import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
   import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
   import EvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
   import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
   import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Button, Left, Body, Right, Item, Input } from 'native-base';
```

The access token:

```
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';
    export default class Landing extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = { 
            header: false
            };
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: "",
            error: "",
          };  
        }

      async storeToken(accessToken){
        try{
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token)
            this.getToken();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
      }

      async getToken(accessToken){
        try{
            let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
           console.log("token is: " + token)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
      }

      async removeToken(){
        try{
          await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
           console.log("token is: " + token)
           this.getToken();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
      }
```

Data fetching:

```
      async onLoginPressed() {
        this.setState({showProgress: true})
        try {      
          let response = await fetch('https://fb3b2e18.ngrok.io/login', {
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                          username: this.state.username,
                          password: this.state.password,
                      })
                    });
          let res = await response.text();
          if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
              //Handle success
              this.setState({error: ""});
              let accessToken = res;
              this.storeToken(accessToken);
              console.log( "res token: " +  accessToken);
              //On success we will store the access_token in the AsyncStorage
              this.storeToken(accessToken);
          } else {
              //Handle error
              let error = res;
              throw error;
          }
        } catch(error) {
            this.removeToken();
            this.setState({error: error});
            console.log("error " + error);
        }
      }
```

> The render method

```
        render() {
          const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
          var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <ImageBackground source={require('./landing.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>              
                  <ScrollView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} style={styles.scrollView}>   
                     <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        Welcome to Flipclip
                      </Text>                                     
                      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', flex: 1,marginBottom: 60}}>                      
                        <Item style={{width: 310,marginBottom: 10}}>
                          <EvilIcons style={{color:'#fefefe'}} name='user' size={20} />
                          <Input 
                            style={{color: '#f5f5f5',fontSize: 14,fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',}} 
                            placeholder='User Name'
                            placeholderTextColor= '#f5f5f5' 
                            onChangeText={ (text)=> this.setState({username: text}) }
                          />
                        </Item>                     
                        <Item style={{width: 310}}>
                          <Icon style={{color:'#fefefe'}} name='ios-lock-outline' size={20}/>
                          <Input 
                            style={{color: '#f5f5f5',fontSize: 14, marginLeft: 5,fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',}} 
                            placeholder='Password'
                            placeholderTextColor= '#f5f5f5' 
                            onChangeText={ (text)=> this.setState({password: text}) }
                          />
                        </Item>
                      </View>
                      <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}>
                        <Button block transparent style={styles.LoginButton} onPress = {this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)}  >
                          <Text style={styles.logintext}>Sign In</Text>
                        </Button>
                      </View>                  
                      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={styles.SignUpResendOtpText}>
                          Don’t have an account?&nbsp;
                          <Text style={styles.SignUpResendOtpLink} onPress = { () => navigate ("SignUp", {}) }>
                            Sign Up
                          </Text>
                        </Text>
                      </View>

                      <Text style={styles.error}>
                        {this.state.error}
                      </Text>
                  </ScrollView>
                </ImageBackground>
            )
        }
    }
```

The styling:

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        scrollView:{
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', 
          flex:1,
        },
        backgroundImage: {
            flex: 1,
            width: null,
            height: null,
        },

        text: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 32,
        },

      uploaderName:{
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#fefefe'
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 28,
        color: '#f5f5f5',
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: 201,
        marginBottom: 135,
        fontFamily: 'FredokaOne-Regular'
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
      LoginButton: {
        borderRadius:100,
        backgroundColor: '#ff0046',
        width: 310, 
        marginBottom: 20,
      },
      logintext:{
        color: '#f5f5f5', 
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
      },
      error: {
        color: 'red',
        paddingTop: 10
      },
      SignUpResendOtpText: {
          color: '#f5f5f5',
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: 14,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',
      },
      SignUpResendOtpLink:{
          color: '#ff0046',
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: 14,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
          textDecorationLine: 'none',
          textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
          textDecorationColor: '#000'
      },
      success: {
        color: 'green',
        paddingTop: 10
      },
    });
```

Comment: maybe look at the docs? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

before

```
<Button block transparent style={styles.LoginButton} onPress = {this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)}  >
```

after

```
<Button block transparent style={styles.LoginButton} onPress = { () => this.onLoginPressed.bind(this) }  >
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am using stack navigator but when I click on login button it just
>   hits the api and nothing happens

This is because you hit the api as you should but you fail to navigate to main app screen once login credentials successful.

So you missing this:

```
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
          //Handle success
          this.setState({error: ""});
          let accessToken = res;
          this.storeToken(accessToken);
    // once successful navigate to another screen
    this.props.navigation.navigate('yourScreen',{}}
}
```